# Not able to receive EOS when streaming .ts file over UDP

Tags: udp, gstreamer, mpeg

I am streaming a .ts file which contains both video and audio over UDP by using below pipeline,

```
   GST_DEBUG=6 gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=vafpd.ts ! tsdemux program-number=10 name=demux demux. ! queue ! h264parse ! muxer.sink_300 mpegtsmux name=muxer prog-map=program_map,sink_300=10,sink_301=10 ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.139 port=8765 sync=true async=true qos=true demux. ! queue ! faad ! faac ! aacparse ! muxer.sink_301
```

It is working fine and receives EOS, whenever the both audio and video durations are same.

But when i streamed a .ts file which has audio and video. and The audio duration is more than the video duration, then **It never ends and never caught EOS.**

When ever the video ends, then below INFO stops printing,

```
0:00:03.392743787  3358       0xa90050 INFO               h264parse gsth264parse.c:1335:gst_h264_parse_update_src_caps:<h264parse0> PAR 1/1
0:00:04.059453486  3358       0xa90050 INFO               baseparse gstbaseparse.c:3644:gst_base_parse_set_latency:<h264parse0> min/max latency 0:00:00.033333333, 0:00:00.033333333
```

These are the log messages,,, After end of the video duration,

```
0:05:19.714110763  3323      0x10ef990 LOG                baseparse gstbaseparse.c:2919:gst_base_parse_chain:<h264parse0> chain leaving
0:05:19.714128717  3323      0x10ef990 LOG           GST_SCHEDULING gstpad.c:3834:gst_pad_chain_data_unchecked:<h264parse0:sink> called chainfunction &gst_base_parse_chain with buffer 0x7f92a8013c00, returned ok
0:05:19.714152324  3323      0x10ef990 DEBUG         queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1277:gst_queue_loop:<queue0> queue is empty
0:05:19.714172126  3323      0x10ef990 LOG           queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1286:gst_queue_loop:<queue0> (queue0:src) wait for ADD: 0 of 0-200 buffers, 0 of 0-10485760 bytes, 0 of 0-1000000000 ns, 0 items
```

**When GST-DEBUG=3,**

```
0:00:00.031284464  3365      0x18ba920 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3483:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.033063992  3365      0x18bc450 WARN               h264parse gsth264parse.c:1025:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame:<h264parse0> broken/invalid nal Type: 9 AU delimiter, Size: 2 will be dropped
0:00:00.047101000  3365      0x18bc4f0 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3064:gst_base_sink_default_event:<udpsink0> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: please don't open milions of similar questions as variation on some task you are supposed to do.. rather update one question..

Comment: k, i will remove the older one

Comment: my personal advise.. imagine that your questions will someday help somebody.. but if you open up many similar unanswered questions it will just confuse newcomers.. for example if somebody react to your question via comment.. and you have some new infos just update the question and if nobody reacts you may ask them via comments..